# How to know userFeePercentage (consume_user_resource_percent) when calling smart-contract?

Tags: api, transactions, blockchain, smartcontracts, tron

I need to **calculate energy fee** for TRC20 transfer.

I can estimate needed energy(energy_usage_total) for transfer and it's price in TRX.

**ESTIMATED ENERGY**: 16482
**CONSTANT CONTRACT**: 14650

How do I calculate the amount of energy (**energy_usage**) that will be spent by the smart contract user
as a result of his call before the transaction itself?

When calling a smart contract, part of the energy is consumed by the developer and I don't understand how I can predict how much energy the developer of the smart contract or the caller will spend.

**Transaction Recipe:**
**FEE:** 346000 
**ENERGY USAGE:**
**ORIGIN ENERGY USAGE:** 14650
**ENERGY USAGE TOTAL:** 14650
**NET FEE:** 346000
**RESULT:** SUCCESS

I also found the **origin_energy_limit** parameter in the smart contract, but I don't understand how to apply it in my situation.

Comment: Please submit your images as plain text format